# How to efficiently save item price map data in Redis instance

Tags: node.js, redis

I have data containing item ids and their prices. I want to put item ids as key and price as values.
The best way I can think of is

```
> set item:1 2300
> set item:2 4300
```

and so on.

But the problem with this is I have to run a loop to set all the data in my node. How can I use a data structure in redis which sets all the key-value pairs in one go and upserts (replaces or inserts) the desired keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MSET` command to set multiple key-value pairs in one go.

Also, both `SET` and `MSET` commands are upserts operations. These commands insert key-value pair if the key doesn't exist, or update the value, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single HSET for this.

```
HMSET HSET:ITEM:PRICES item:1 2300 item:2 4300 item:3 5800 item:<ID> <PRICE> ...
```

For more memory efficiency you can remove 'item:' from field names (redis will use only 4+4 bytes for each such entry in memory).

```
HMSET HSET:ITEM:PRICES 1 2300 2 4300 3 5800 <ID> <PRICE> ...
```

Then if you want to retrieve the prices for items 1 and 2

```
HMGET HSET:ITEM:PRICES item:1 item:2
```

or if you are using more efficient way just:

```
HMGET HSET:ITEM:PRICES 1 2
```